# What is the Unexpected Token syntax error in line six?

Tags: linux, syntax-error, blockchain, ethereum

I'm trying to learn how to create NFTs on the Ethereum block chain.

In terminal (Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS)

`Aki-Zeta:~/my-nft$ node scripts/mint-nft.js`

I keep getting

```
/home/patonn89/my-nft/scripts/mint-nft.js:6
const { createAlchemyWeb3 } 
                          ^
Syntax Error Unexpected Token {
```

*see bottom for full error*

Here is my code using VScode

```
require("dotenv").config()
const API_URL = process.env.API_URL;
const PUBLIC_KEY = process.env.PUBLIC_KEY;
const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;

const { createAlchemyWeb3 } = require("@alch/alchemy-web3")
const web3 = createAlchemyWeb3(API_URL)

const contract = require("../artifacts/contracts/MyNFT.sol/MyNFT.json")
const contractAddress = "0xf469355dc12e00d8cda65b3a465bdad65da27e22"
const nftContract = new web3.eth.Contract(contract.abi, contractAddress)

async function mintNFT(tokenURI) {
    const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(PUBLIC_KEY, 'latest'); //get latest nonce

  //the transaction
    const tx = {
      'from': PUBLIC_KEY,
      'to': contractAddress,
      'nonce': nonce,
      'gas': 500000,
      'data': nftContract.methods.mintNFT(PUBLIC_KEY, tokenURI).encodeABI(),
    }

    const signPromise = web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, PRIVATE_KEY)
  signPromise
    .then((signedTx) => {
      web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(
        signedTx.rawTransaction,
        function (err, hash) {
          if (!err) {
            console.log(
              "The hash of your transaction is: ",
              hash,
              "\nCheck Alchemy's Mempool to view the status of your transaction!"
            )
          } else {
            console.log(
              "Something went wrong when submitting your transaction:",
              err
            )
          }
        }
      )
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(" Promise failed:", err)
    })
  }​

  mintNFT( 
      "https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmcRikKfA6xdaNZkojW28xpvZYysQXSJEb52YdeRJP3GGv"
      )
```

Is it something to do with that "{" in line 6, or something else in line 6?
Prior to running this script I ran "npm install @alch/alchemy-web3", and verified the directories exist (both by going there and with cd). Other people with similar issues are missing something, and I have no idea what I'm missing. I have checked for spurious spaces and semicolons but I am not experienced with this language.

I have been using the tutorials off of the [Ethereum project](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/how-to-mint-an-nft/) site.

**full error**

```
/home/patonn89/my-nft/scripts/mint-nft.js:6
const { createAlchemyWeb3 } 
                          ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:448:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:471:10)
    at startup (node.js:117:18)
    at node.js:951:3
```

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same error, and it was just a spurious character in my VScode editor, same example as you from ethereum.org.

As you can see in line 24

[image: screenshot of VScode]

Answer (score 0):

change `const { createAlchemyWeb3 }` to `const { createAlchemyWeb3 } = require("@alch/alchemy-web3")`